# how to pass the key? to _buildWidgets?

Tags: flutter

Hi i am trying to pass following key to _buildEmailTF
what is the best way to pass key to _buildEmailTF()?
Thank you Please help me.

final TextEditingController? controller;final bool? obsecureText final String hintText; final validator;

```
Widget _buildEmailTF() {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text(
          'Email',
          style: kLabelStyle,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10.0,
        ),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          decoration: kBoxDecorationStyle,
          height: 60,
          child: TextField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'OpenSans'),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                    const Radius.circular(30.0),
                  ),
                ),
                focusedErrorBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                    const Radius.circular(30.0),
                  ),
                ),
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 14.0),
                prefixIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.email,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                hintText: 'Enter your Email',
                hintStyle: kHintTextStyle),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }`
```

Comment: you can pass by parameter or if it is within the scope you might not have to pass it, can you include full widget?

Answer (score 0):

Widget _buildEmailTF( @yourkey ) { ... }